# Jekyll --watch command not working in shared folder (nfs) Mac host machine using Virtual box Ubuntu guest machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, jekyll, nfs, watch

I have a Virtual Box VM running Ubuntu. I have configured an nsf share (when I say I, someone helped me so I am not very clued up on NFS shares) so that I can work on my Mac host machine and use it's tools such as Sublime Text.

However, when I run the following command: `jekyll serve --watch`

When I make code changes the site is not automatically regenerated. So currently I have to stop the server and run the command again.

**EDIT:**

Additionally it works fine if I create a jekyll site outside of the nfs share. Just a standard normal folder on the guest machine.

Comment: What version of jekyll are you running? Run `jekyll -v` to see.

Comment: I found this, poking around: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1763 - it seems that after `jekyll 1.2.1` you just need to use force polling (add `--force_polling`) for VirtualBox because `inotify` events are not sent for shared folders (as expected) so `jekyll` has to poll the files manually instead. Apparently `jekyll` used to force poll by default up to 1.2.1, which changed later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then uninstall Jekyll v 1.4.2 and install Jekyll v 1.2.1

To do so run these commands,

```
gem uninstall jekyll
y
gem install jekyll -v 1.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to install an older version of jekyll - you need to use `--force_polling`. Explanation follows:

VirtualBox will not send `inotify` events for shared folders to the guest. This is intentional:

- https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10660

jekyll up to version 1.2.1 would poll directories for changes by default, but it has since changed the way it listens for modifications, apparently to use `inotify` events, which works better. This *does* break listening on shared folders though but the old behavior can be forced using the `--force_polling` option along with `--watch` when using `build` or `serve`:

```
jekyll serve --watch --force_polling
```

I found this out from a related issue on jekyll's repo:

- https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1763

**update**: I've now started using jekyll through VirtualBox myself and have found that there is a slight issue sometimes with jekyll watching files through a shared folder: it reads file modifications wrong, resulting in files that should be copied unmodified to the generated site being identical to their previous version except there's garbage carriage returns at the end (yes, even if the file format is set to unix line endings). To resolve this, you can use `rsync` to copy the files to the virtual hard drive and have jekyll watch that directory instead:

```
rsync -a --recursive --delete /source/directory/ /target/directory/inside/vm/
```

to keep it automated, you can turn the above into a script (or not) and use `watch`:

```
watch -n1 /path/to/rsync/script.sh
```

then just have jekyll watch the target directory and it works fine. If you do it this way, `--force_polling` shouldn't be necessary unless somehow your virtualized OS isn't using `inotify` events. I've left it as is and I haven't had any issues although clearly `inotify` events are a more elegant way of treating the problem.

Comment: it's force_polling not force-polling

Comment: @Emad right you are, corrected. Wrote this post before I started using jekyll this way :P

Answer (score -1):

Update to Latest version of Jekyll, or atleast to Jekyll v 1.2.1

Comment: I am currently using 1.4.2